# Double cannot be derefereced Java compiler error

Tags: java, arrays, methods, double

```
public void additionHW() {
     for(Subject y: sub) {
       for (double s: s.getHomeworkMark()) {
          homeworkAddition += s;
        }
     }

     s.addToTotalHW.add(homeworkAddition);
    }
```

I'm getting an error saying double cannot be dereferenced...

ANy ideas??

Comment: `s.getHomeworkMark()` should probably be `y.getHomeworkMark()`

Comment: Where are you getting the error, and what does `getHomeworkMark()` return?

Comment: @SabujHassan: Same error, probably different fundamental cause.

Comment: Along with Rohit's comment, be sure to look at `s.addToTotalHW.add(homeworkAddition);` where you have a similar problem. At this point `s` is out of scope and even if it wasn't you can't call methods on a primitive data type.

Comment: I don't think `for (Type x : x.method(...)...)` can ever possibly compile.  At best it will give `variable x might not have been initialized`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably wanted was

```
y.getHomeworkMark()
```

(if it returns an `Array/Collection`), since `s` is a `double` and doesn't have that method.

Answer (score 1):

You are using fast enumeration while declaring an element with the same name as some object `s` which provides an `array` of `double`s or `Collection` of `Double` through method `getHomeworkMark`.

I suspect you wanted to reference element `y` of your `sub` `array` / `Collection`:

```
for (double s: y.getHomeworkMark()) {
```